# Finding the values of $a$ and $b$ so that the plane $ax+by+2z+1 = 0$ intersect two other planes in a line

Tags: linear-algebra

**I working on this problem:** 
Find the values of $a$ and $b$ so that the plane  $P_3 = ax+by+2z+1 = 0$ intersect the two other planes:
$$P_2 = x-2y+z+5 = 0,P_1 = 3x-3y-2z-1 = 0$$
in a line and describe the intersection line in parameter form.

**My work:**

We first try to find the line of intersection of the given planes $P_1, P_2$:

$x-2y+z+5 = 0$
$3x-3y-2z-1 = 0$

with elimination this gives us:

$3y -5z -16 = 0$ and with $z = t$

$x = -\frac{17}{3} + \frac{7t}{3}, y = \frac{16}{3} + \frac{5t}{3}, z = t$

Which is the parametric equation of the intersection line of the planes $P_1, P_2$. Now we need to find the values for $a, b$ that makes the plane $ax+by+2z+1 = 0$ parallell to the line.

This happens when the normal vector and the gradient vector are orthogonal:

$$(a, b, 2) \cdot (7,5,3) = 0 \rightarrow -7a = 5b +6$$

From this i can guess the right answer $a = -3, b = 3$ but obviously I need more information to solve this properly, what else can I do to work this out?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane should not only be parallel to the line, it should contain the line as well. For this, find an arbitrary point on the line (for example, $t = 2 \rightarrow (-11, 12, 2)$ and substitute it in the equation of the plane ($-11a + 12b + 2(2) + 1 = 0$). Now you have two linear equations which you can solve to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you have the time and patience to do the calculations for this I would be very happy. Otherwise I will accept your answer as it is. Thank you!

Comment: @LukasArvidsson You should really do that yourself, as the point is for you to learn. I already edited the answer to include the second equation, though. Just the solve the two equations.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that!